# query in stetho not working when pressing enter key

Tags: android, stetho

I have been using android debug mode and tried to query data through Stetho in 'Resources' section. When I typed query and press enter key, it does not show me the result I want whereas it adds another empty line underneath the query I typed.

example

```
Select * From employees
```

and then I pressed the enter key.

result

```
Select * From employees
<new line starts here>
```

I am wondering how it happened and hoping to find the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

seems not working on chrome 72, try use version 71 to work around.

https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/634

Comment: Is this still an issue in August 2019?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky seems working fine now on latest chrome

Comment: I have the same issue on Chrome v83

Comment: it was frustrating at that time because i used stetho to check the data from both android emulator and android device. as Data Inspector comes out on new version of Android Studio, so this might be helpful for those who do not use the new version of Android Studio or on non-android developers

Answer (score 0):

To me this is the last straw for Stetho and `chrome://inspect`

I have switched to [Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/), a similar debugging tool developed by Facebook.

The developer experience is much better, as can be seen below:[image: picture of UX for database inpsection in Flipper]